# Mock class in phpunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm finally getting into PHP unit testing (yeah better late than never!)

I have a `Utility` class that does a few things including authenticating a user's access against a webservice. The `Utility::authenticate` method takes a `Settings` object, which contains the username etc. that are checked by `authenticate`.

So in my test, I mock a `Settings` object like this:

```
$settings = $this->getMock('Settings', array('getSettings'));

$settings->method('getSettings')
    ->willReturn([
        'USERNAME' => 'testuser',
        'SERVER' => 'testserver'
    ]);

$mock = $settings->getSettings();
```

So far so good, but when I try to pass that mocked object to `authenticate` it throws an error:

```
$this->assertEquals($testvalue, Utilities::authenticate($settings));
Argument 1 passed to Utilities::authenticate() must be an instance of Settings, instance of Mock_Settings_d0361624 given
```

How can I mock the `Settings` object so it appears to be a "real" object to the `Utilities` class?

EDIT to add the getSettings function:

```
class Settings {

private $settings;
private static $instance;

public function __construct(){
    $configfile = "config/config.ini";
    //if( !$this->settings = parse_ini_file( $configfile, true ) ){
        //die('SETTINGS OBJECT NOT FOUND OR COULD NOT BE PARSEd');
    //}
}
/**
 * @return Settings
 */
public static function getSettings(){
    if ( !self::$instance ){
        self::$instance = new Settings();
    }
    if(!utilities::authenticate(self::$instance)) die('AUTHENTICATION FAILED-- CHECK API KEY');
    return self::$instance;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the tested method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message occur when you create the object with a wrong classname. Check the `getMock` method pass the full classname with the namespace, like:

```
$settings = $this->getMock('Acme\DemoBundle\Model\Settings', array('getSettings'));
```

Hope this help

**EDIT**

The method is static and the phpunit library don't support mock **static** method as described [here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-documentation/issues/77) and [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).

So you can use some mockking framework such as [Phake](http://phake.readthedocs.org/en/2.1/index.html) that support mocking static method as described [here](http://phake.readthedocs.org/en/2.1/mocking-statics.html). As working example:

```
public function test_authenticate()
{
    $settings = \Phake::mock('Acme\DemoBundle\Model\Settings');

    \Phake::whenStatic($settings)
        ->getSettings()
        ->thenReturn([
            'USERNAME' => 'testuser',
            'SERVER' => 'testserver'
        ]);

    $mock = $settings->getSettings();

    $testvalue = true;
    $this->assertEquals($testvalue, Utilities::authenticate($settings));
}
```

Comment: @matteo-- thanks! however now it's complaining: `PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_BadMethodCallException`  in the line `$mock = $settings->getSettings();`

Comment: Ensure you return what you need.  The manual is here -> https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

Comment: Hi @user101289 can you post the code of the `getSettings` method?

Comment: Hi @user101289 see my update. You really need that `getSettings` is a static method?

Comment: Hi @user101289 have you take a look at my answer? what you think about it?